# How to save as "n/a" in MS Access?

Tags: vb.net, oledb

Even if I uncheck the CheckBox, it will save the default text written on it.
This code is for my self study.

```
Private Sub btnADD_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnADD.Click

    Dim provider1 As String
    Dim dataFile1 As String
    Dim connString1 As String
    Dim myConnection1 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    provider1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source ="
    dataFile1 = "|DataDirectory|\dbSentinel.accdb"
    connString1 = provider1 & dataFile1
    myConnection1.ConnectionString = connString1
    myConnection1.Open()

    Dim str As String
    str = "Insert into tblComputerDesktopInventory([DesktopName],[Department],OperatingSystem],[MOBOmanufacturer],[MOBOproduct],[MOBOserial],[MOBOspecs],[HDDmanufacturer],[HDDcapacity],[HDDserial],[ACCmonitor],ACCmodel],[ACCserial],[ACCmouse],[ACCkeyboard],[ACCmousepad],[ACCheadset],[RAMmanufacturer],[RAMcapacity],[RAMserial]) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection1)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("DesktopName", CType(txtDesktopName.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Department", CType(cboDepartment.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("OperatingSystem", CType(cboOperatingSystem.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("MOBOmanufacturer", CType(txtMOBOmanufacturer.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("MOBOproduct", CType(txtMOBOproduct.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("MOBOserial", CType(txtMOBOserial.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("MOBOspecs", CType(txtMOBOspecs.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("HDDmanufacturer", CType(txtHDDmanufacturer.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("HDDcapacity", CType(txtHDDcapacity.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("HDDserial", CType(txtHDDserial.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ACCmonitor", CType(txtACCmonitor.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ACCmodel", CType(txtACCmodel.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ACCserial", CType(txtACCserial.Text, String)))
    'the next line starts a checkbox
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ACCmouse", CType(chkmouse.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ACCkeyboard", CType(chkkeyboard.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ACCmousepad", CType(chkmousepad.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ACCheadset", CType(chkheadset.Text, String)))
    'end of checkbox
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("RAMmanufacturer", CType(txtRAMmanufacturer.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("RAMcapacity", CType(txtRAMcapacity.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("RAMserial", CType(txtRAMserial.Text, String)))
End sub
```

Comment: Given that the `Text` property of a control is type `String`, what's the point of using `CType(myControl.Text, String)` rather than just `muControl.Text`?

Comment: You should not be using the `Text` property of a `CheckBox`. That's just the text displayed next to the box. The property of relevance is the `Checked` property or, if you are using three states, the `CheckState` property.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ACCheadset", CType(chkheadset.CheckState, String))) 

doesnt happen.

Comment: Why would you even expect it to? Why do you think converting a `CheckState` value to a `String` and saving that would be a good idea? What value do you actually expect to get saved to the database?